# Browser Back-Button jump to last location (like maps.google.com)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

What I do is I go to a location in Google Maps (either by searching or just by dragging the map). Now I enter another URL in the addressbar and hit return to go to that site.

When I use the browser Back-Button, google Maps automatically switches back to the location I was last in.

How is this done if I dragged the map and didn't use some kind of "POST" on the Google Maps site? I would like to have the same behaviour in my own google Google Maps App.

I'm using Google Maps API for JavaScript v3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you just look for an event called '**dragend**' on your map

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function() {

});
```

Then you need to get your coordinates using **getCenter**() and redirect your browser to '#coordinates' it won't reload your window as you use hash, but it will save it in history.

```
coords = map.getCenter();
window.location = '#' + encodeURI(coords);
```

Now you need to add listener to check for any 'hash' changes in an URL (assuming you have jQuery)

```
$(window).bind('hashchange', function () {
    var hash = window.location.hash.slice(1);
});
```

At the end you need to tell your map to change coordinates and decode url

```
hash = decodeURL(hash);
map.panTo(hash);
```

Instead of **panTo**() you could use **setCenter**(), but it add some nice animation while clicking Back button.

It is very easy to change this code to work with your searched place, you can use event '**center_changed**' instead of '**dragend**' and it will handle everything.

Everything I wrote about is covered here:

> https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you - this sounds like a reasonable approach and I will give feedback as soon as I solved it.

Comment: I start to think that this is a pretty unclean way for me to do it that way. Then thing is, I have to store more than just the coordinates and I don't want everything visible in the URL and it doesn't have to be bookmarkable either.

What's interesting is, that Google Maps doesn't use Hashtags either. And i think it doesn't even use the Browser's History. I don't have a clue how they do it...

Comment: You actually don't need to store coordinates in hashes, you can save cities for example... In that aproach you have your markers array somewhere generated on the site anyways, so you can just refer your hashes to that information...

Comment: Does the `$(window).bind...()` line also go inside the `dragend` event?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if GMaps has convenience method for this, but generally such functionality is based on HTML5 `history.pushState()` which lets you add custom steps to navigation history and observe when user navigates back:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

If you want to handle more advanced application states this way, there are several frameworks built on top of it, e.g. [Backbone router](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#History-start), [LeviRoutes](https://github.com/PaulKinlan/leviroutes).

In HTML4 browsers `pushState` can be [emulated with fragment identifiers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onhashchange) (hash URLs).

Comment: Thanks for this general approach - I will probably go with the solution pointed out by Turek (and you in the last sentence) but it's good to know about pushState().